# print both side

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook consist of 200 worksheets that I need to print out.

some of them are 1 page long and some of them are 2 pages long on a worksheet.

I want to print on both sides, but when I do that, it puts different worksheets together on both sides.

I need every single worksheet on a different paper, if a worksheet is 1 page, I need it on one paper and the next 1 page long worksheet on a different paper.

Is there a way to do that using VBA?

please help !

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide the code you actually use in your question. *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.**"*

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
Sub print_all()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.PrintOut
    Next ws
End Sub
```

This loops through all worksheets in the workbook, then prints each page out individually. Note that it prints to the default printer, but you can set which printer by setting the `ActivePrinter` parameter for the `PrintOut` method.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed !

Answer (score 0):

it is a difference if you use one `.PrintOut` for multiple sheets like

```
Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "sheet3")).PrintOut
```

or using a `.PrintOut` for each sheet on its own.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").PrintOut
Sheets("Sheet2").PrintOut
Sheets("sheet3").PrintOut
```

- The first one will continuously print all sheets duplex (as they were one sheet only)
- while the second will print single page sheets on a single sheet of paper (leaving the backside blank) and multi-page sheets duplex. It will never print 2 different sheets on one sheet of paper.